# When using templates, is it possible to determine the type of Lvalue?

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

It's sort of hard to put it into words, so here's an example instead:

```
int (*foo)(int) = load_sym<decltype(foo)>("foo");

template <typename T>
T load_sym(char *sym) {
    /* some other stuff */
    return (T)dlsym(sym);
}
```

If possible I'd like to omit the `decltype(foo)` part to make it succinct.  The question is, can I determine `T` without having to explicitly specify it as a template argument?

Gut feeling that it's probably not possible, but I'm curious to know if people have come up with work around.

Comment: There *is* a workaround but it's far nastier than the `auto` job done by Brian.

Comment: Don't think Brian's solution would work with a class member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that avoids `auto` and works in the case of a non-static data member, but is a bit ugly.

```
struct Symbol {
  Symbol(void* p) : p(p) {}
  template <typename T>
  operator T*() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(p); }
  void* p;
};

Symbol load_sym(const char *sym) {
    /* some other stuff */
    return dlsym(sym);
}
```

Now you can do

```
int (*foo)(int) = load_sym("foo");
```

The `Symbol` class simply stores the return value of `load_sym`, but provides a conversion operator template that can be used to convert the `void*` to a pointer of any type.

(Note that conversion of `void*` to function pointer type is conditionally supported, but I believe POSIX requires it.)

Comment: I guess that works, but seems like too much trouble.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
auto foo = load_sym<int (*)(int)>("foo");
```

Comment: That's fine too, but I'm still curious to see if the original question is possible or not.  I'd rather avoid this because `foo` in my case is a class member, which I'd rather not `auto` (not even sure if it's `auto`-able).